# Does this class of groups contain finitely generated infinite periodic groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups, computational-group-theory

Let $r(m)$ denote the residue class $r+m\mathbb{Z}$, where $0 \leq r < m$.
Given disjoint residue classes $r_1(m_1)$ and $r_2(m_2)$, let the *class transposition*
$\tau_{r_1(m_1),r_2(m_2)}$ be the permutation of $\mathbb{Z}$ which interchanges
$r_1+km_1$ and $r_2+km_2$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and which fixes everything else.

> **Question:** Does the group ${\rm CT}(\mathbb{Z})$ generated by the set of
>   all class transpositions have finitely generated infinite periodic subgroups?

*Remark:* By means of computation one can find "almost-examples" of such groups.
For example let $G := \langle a, b, c, d, e \rangle$, where $a = \tau_{0(4),2(4)}$,
$b = \tau_{0(5),3(5)}$, $c = \tau_{1(3),5(6)}$, $d = \tau_{1(6),3(6)}$ and
$e = \tau_{2(6),4(6)}$. Then $G$ is infinite, but the subgroups generated by any $4$
of the generators are finite, and also all products of at most $6$ generators have
finite order. Though unfortunately there are products of $7$ generators which happen
to have infinite order (example: $(ab)^2ced$), such that $G$ is not periodic.

**Added on May 15, 2018:** This question has appeared as Problem 19.46 in:

[Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org/): *Unsolved Problems in Group Theory.*
Editors V. D. Mazurov, E. I. Khukhro. 19th Edition, Novosibirsk 2018.

Comment: Remark: this group a topological-full group, namely on the space $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ (profinite completion of the group of integers), of the groupoid induced by the partial multiplicative action of positive rationals.

Comment: @YCor: As I don't know anything about topological full groups -- do you think that this is a 'substantial' characterization in the sense that one can plausibly exploit it to investigate CT($\mathbb{Z}$) and to obtain results which wouldn't be easy to obtain otherwise?

Comment: Maybe more a way to anticipate on results, which would then be easy to obtain otherwise? indeed it yields an intuition. Simplicity of the derived subgroup holds in a very general context (see Nekrashevych, *Groups of dynamical origin*), but you know it and actually know bare simplicity, if I remember correctly. Also Matte Bon constructed periodic  (infinite f.g.) subgroups in suitable full topological groups, and this was generalized by Nekrashevych (*Palindromic subshifts...*), maybe this can help, or not, I don't know.

Comment: @YCor: To get back to your comment. -- May it be that your observation that CT($\mathbb{Z}$) is a topological-full group gives rise to a cheap (positive) answer to what I posed as Problem 17.59 in the [Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org/)? -- If so, this would be a quite substantial conclusion. (If the answer to the problem would be negative, then the simple group CT(Z) would be a proper normal subgroup of the (also topological-full?) group of all residue-class-wise affine permutations of Z which fix the nonnegative integers setwise).

Comment: Possibly I wrote a bit quickly: the group which is, essentially by definition, clearly a topological-full group, is the whole group of all residue-class-wise affine permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @YCor: Ah, I see. -- But does that hold for the setwise stabilizer of the nonnegative integers as well?

Comment: There are topological-full groups, naturally acting on $\mathbf{Z}$, in which the set-wise stabilizer of $\mathbf{N}$ have indeed been studied and are interesting. These are indeed topological full-groups, namely restricting to partial affine maps that preserve $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: @YCor: Which such groups have been studied so far, for example?

Comment: The most studied have been topological-full groups of a minimal self-homeomorphism of the Cantor set on the one hand, and, in the groupoid setting, the Thompson-Higman groups ($V$ and generalizations).