# Special sets of involutions generating ${\rm S}_n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-groups

For which positive integers $k$ and $r$ are there involutions $g_{n,i} \in {\rm S}_n$
$(n \in \mathbb{N}, \ i = 1, \dots, k)$ such that the following hold?:

- for any $n$, the $g_{n,i}$ $(i = 1, \dots, k)$ generate ${\rm S}_n$,
- there is a uniform upper bound on the orders of the groups generated by all but one
  of the $k$ generators $g_{n,i}$ $(i = 1, \dots, k)$, valid for *all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and
- there is a uniform upper bound on the orders of all words of length $\leq r$ in the
  $g_{n,i}$ $(i = 1, \dots, k)$, valid for *all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*Remark:* The motivation for asking this question is that when trying to find an answer to
[this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169232/does-this-class-of-groups-contain-finitely-generated-infinite-periodic-groups), I came across a way to construct such permutations in the case $k = r = 6$,
but only for $n$ congruent to $4$ or $15$ modulo $24$.