# Uncountable chains of countable simple groups -- reference request

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

**Question:** Which examples of uncountable ascending / descending chains
of countable simple groups have been described in the literature so far?

*Remark:* The question is not whether such chains do exist at all
(the answer to this being *yes*).

Comment: Uncountable inclusion chains in countable sets are well-known, perhaps chains free abelian groups generated by them are documented somewhere, but I don't have an exact reference.

Comment: Not answering the question, but just to give examples: any chain isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}$ yields a chain of type $\mathbf{R}$ (by completion). Chain of type $\mathbf{Q}$ of countable fields are easy to construct (even within algebraic extensions of finite fields). Also, by transfinite induction one can produce ascending chains of countable fields of type $\omega_1$. Taking $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ , one gets accordingly chains of countable simple groups, of type $\mathbf{Q}$ and of type $\omega_1$ (includings chains of locally finite simple groups of type $\omega_1$).

Comment: (2) Other family directly following from known material: let $S=\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$ be the circle group. For an infinite subgroup $H$ of $S$, let $IET(H)$ be the group of interval exchanges with translations and breakpoints in $H$. It is known that its derived subgroup is a simple group (e.g. by general results of Matui and Nekrashevych on topological-full groups). Finding uncountable chains of countable (abelian) subgroups of $S$ is easy (of type $\mathbf{Q}$ or $\omega_1$). Taking the corresponding $IET(H)'$ yield the desired chain.

Comment: (3) one more remark. Phillip Hall proved that every countable group embeds into a finitely generated simple group (with 9, the 3 generators, improved to 2 by Schupp). Using this, a transfinite induction yields (not constructively) an ascending chain of (2-generated) finitely generated simple groups, of type $\omega_1$.

Comment: (4) sorry for the lengthy list of comments, but an even easier example:  let $X$ be an uncountable set and $(X_i)$ a chain of countable subsets. Then the alternating group $\mathrm{Alt}(X_i)$ on $X_i$ is a simple group, they just form a chain as well, of locally finite groups. The chain can be chosen of type $\mathbf{Q}$ or $\omega_1$.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you very much for your extended list of examples! -- Though for the finitary alternating groups example, you can also choose $X$ to be countable, and things do still work. By the way -- besides that example, the example I had in mind when asking this question was a chain of subgroups of the group CT($\mathbb{Z}$) from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169232/).

Comment: @StefanKohl for the alternating example $X$ can be chosen countable for chains of type $\mathbf{Q}$ (in this case the union of $X_i$ is countable automatically), but not for chains of type $\omega_1$ for which we need $X$ of cardinal $\aleph_1$. By the way, with a mixture, we get chains isomorphic to the (right half of the) long line.

Comment: @YCor: Sorry for asking -- but what do you denote by a "chain of type **Q**", respectively, a "chain of type $\omega_1$"? -- I am not familiar with this terminology, and Google does not seem to be of much help here.

Comment: Indeed for $CT(\mathbf{Z})$, you have the poset of subrings $\mathbf{Z}[P^{-1}]$ where $P$ ranges over the power set of the set of primes; it thus embeds into the poset of simple subgroups of $CT(\mathbf{Z})$. It's analogous to the case of IET (both are topological-full groups).

Comment: @StefanKohl I'm not sure it's standard terminology. A chain of type $I$ in the set of subgroups of a given group $G$ is a set of subgroups that is totally order under inclusion, and the order set is isomorphic to $I$. Here $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal. Any chain $(H_s)_{s\in\mathbf{Q}}$ of type $\mathbf{Q}$ of subgroups of $G$ extends to a chain of type $\mathbf{R}$, by mapping any irrational $r$ to $\bigcup_{s<r}H_s$.

Comment: @YCor: Ah, I see -- you don't assume the continuum hypothesis here, and thus the difference(?)

Comment: Yes I don't assume CH. These are "independent" chains:  Indeed, for $\alpha\ge\omega_1$, the chain of normal subgroups of the symmetric group $\mathrm{Sym}(\aleph_\alpha)$ contains a subchain isomorphic to $\omega_1$, but not to $\mathbf{Q}$, while the chain of normal subgroups of, say, the group $\mathbf{Q}$, contains a subposet isomorphic to $2^\omega$ and hence a chain isomorphic $\mathbf{R}$, but contains no subchain isomorphic to $\omega_1$.

Comment: (Even under CH there's a difference, by my previous comment. The "complexity" a of chain is not just given by its cardinal.)

Comment: @StefanKohl Re: $\omega_1$ versus $\mathbb{R}$, neither embeds as a linear order into the other, due to the second countability of $\mathbb{R}$ in one direction and the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$ in the other.